# Uploading iphone application

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create archive of my iphone  project. The archive is created but it has no version and identifier information.version is Unspecified and identifier is blank.

In my target summary page everything(version and identifier)are fine. I am using Xcode 4.3

Comment: did u configure both target and projct?

Comment: How does your Info.plist look like and do you have valid distribution provisioning profile?

Comment: My distribution provisioning profile is valid , properly done the bundle identifier in info.plist and I configured the target and project.But I dont know this configuration is right or not.Please give me the configuration details